# Expected Card Advantage in YGO - Going beyond the multivariate hypergeometric formula

Tags: probability, reference-request, card-games

*If you like you can recast everything below as a problem about drawing $k$ balls of $M$ different colors from an urn without replacement.*

There is a famous trading card game that is abbreviated as YGO. In this game you may select the deck of cards you are using yourself before you play.
Naturally, this leads to the overarching question: What cards do I play and in which quantities should I play them? Usually, (but not always) the different types of cards can be written as a partition of the entire deck for the purpose of formulating these questions.

We will be thinking of our opening hand. If we just want to know something like "what is the probability of opening X of card type A" we can use the probability density of the hypergeometric distribution and we can generalize this to more than 2 types of cards using the multivariate hypergeometric distribution.

But the questions that come up are often times significantly more complicated than that.
Instead of probabilities of opening hands I want to generalize to expected "payoffs".
I'll call this expected *card advantage* of our opening hand.

One "simple" definition of expected card advantage could be

$$\mathbb E[\max_{i\leq j \leq M} \lambda_{i,j} 1_{\{n_i \geq 1\}} 1_{\{n_j \geq 1\}}].$$

Here we have partitioned our deck into $M$ classes (types of cards). We draw $k$ cards in our opening hand and $n_i$ is the number of cards in our opening hand that are from class $i$.

In game jargon we would say that the probability $\mathbb P(n_i \geq 1, n_j \geq 1)$ is the probability of *opening a two-card combo* with cards from $i$ and $j$ (although we also include the possibility of *one-card combos*, since we can have $i=j$). Then $\lambda_{i,j}$ would be the card advantage I would get if I played that combo. Usually, I can only play one combo, which is why I always want to play the one generating the maximal card advantage. Hence, the $\max$.

I'm very ignorant about the literature on urn models. I wonder how or whether we can efficiently compute the expected card advantage. My question is:

**Has this or a more general question been studied before and where can I read about that?**

We can probably recast this problem into a purely combinatorial problem, although I'm not sure this will make it easier to find the right book.

---

I wanted to actually give a semi-realistic example of how $\lambda$ could look like. For simplicity I only consider $i\neq j$.

I have $M = 5$ classes with sizes

G: 3, S: 3, F: 3, JJ: 3, T: 28.

Then $\lambda$ is

$$\begin{pmatrix}  & G & S & F & JJ & T \\
 G & 4 & 6 & 4.7 & 4 & 5 \\
 S & 6 & 2 & 6 & 2 & 3 \\
 F & 4.7 & 6 & 2.7 & 2.7 & 3.7 \\
 JJ & 4 & 2 & 2.7 & 2 & 3 \\
 T & 5 & 3 & 3.7 & 3 & 2 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

As you can see we cannot expect any kind of sparsity in the matrix.

*Note: this is very, very rough payoff matrix for the so called Salamangreat deck (Classes: Gazelle, Spinny, Foxy, Jack Jaguar or Falco, and Tech choices). I ignored stuff like Circle, Cynet mining, Lady debug to keep it "simple". I count card advantage gained, including Salads which are live in the GY for the next turn. Techs are considered to always give +1. The trap you search using Gazelle (if you can) counts as a +2. The .7 comes from the approximate probability of using Foxy's first effect to excavate.*

Comment: You may need to consider "small" cases - i.e., the actual case where a maximum of 3 cards of the same are allowed in the deck. This would be interesting for various deck-milling styles of play. (Yes, I played a fair bit of Yu-Gi-Oh in the day, and sad that this is posted on the day we found the creator passed.)

Comment: OOF. Im sorry, this is bad timing. Maybe I should have waited until tomorrow.

Comment: But to clarify: the class sizes don't necessarily refer to individual cards, but also to types like "level 3 extenders" or something like that. Modern Yugioh is many way very different from, say, YGO 10 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

### With free choice of hand size, the problem is NP-hard

We will reduce the decision version of [vertex cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover) to this.

- The deck contains one unique card $i$ for every vertex $i$ in the graph.
- Let each hand represent the complement of a prospective cover, i.e. the cards represent the vertexes *not* in the cover.
- Let the hand size be equal to the number of vertexes in the graph minus the target number of vertexes in the cover.
- The value of a combo is $\lambda_{ij} = 1$ if edge $ij$ exists in the graph, and $\lambda_{ij} = 0$ otherwise.

Then the value of a hand is $1$ iff there is some edge in the graph that is not covered, i.e. both endpoints of the edge were selected to *not* be in the prospective cover. If there is no vertex cover of the desired size, then every hand is worth $1$ and the expected value of the max combo is $1$; if there is such a vertex cover, then the value for the corresponding hand is $0$ (i.e. no edges were left out) and the expected value of the max combo is less than $1$.

### "Single-pass" evaluation

We will want to find some exploitable structure in "typical" combo functions. I recently published a [paper](https://ojs.aaai.org/index.php/AIIDE/article/view/21971) that may help, depending on the structure of the payoff matrix (or tensor) $\lambda$.

Consider the following process of evaluating a hand of cards:

- First, I tell you how many aces you drew.
- Then, I tell you how many twos you drew.
- Then, I tell you how many threes you drew.
- ...

You can remember things between each step, and update your memory at each step, such that at the end you can determine the max payoff of the hand. In terms of Python code with a transition function `next_state`:

```
state = None
state = next_state(state, 1, num_ones)
state = next_state(state, 2, num_twos)
state = next_state(state, 3, num_threes)
# ...
```

Given such a transition function, the output of the algorithm is the distribution of max payoffs of a random hand. From here, the expected value can be computed using the weighted mean.

In the worst case, you would have to remember every previous card you drew, in which case the algorithm has no advantage over iterating over all possible hands with the multivariate hypergeometric formula. However, if you can determine the payoff of a hand while retaining less information than this, the algorithm can find the distribution of payoffs more efficiently.

### Examples of exploitable structure

#### Longest straight

For example, this transition function looks for the longest straight in your hand:

```
def next_state(state, outcome, count):
    best_run, best_run_outcome, run = state or (0, outcome, 0)
    if count >= 1:
        run += 1
    else:
        run = 0
    return max((run, outcome), (best_run, best_run_outcome)) + (run,)
```

In this case, you don't need to remember every previous card, only the length of the current run and the best run you've seen so far.

#### Sums

Another example, which may be applicable to "tech" cards, is to simply sum the value of each card:

```
def next_state(state, outcome, count):
    return (state or 0) + outcome * count
```

Ideally the number of possible unique sums is small, e.g. if the payoffs of each tech card is a small integer.

#### Band matrix

If the payoff matrix $\lambda$ can be permuted into a [band matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_matrix) with bandwidth $b$ (or analogously for tensors), then you can check for the best combo while only remembering whether the most recent $b$ classes have been drawn. For $p$ unique payoff values, the number of unique states would then be at most $2^b p$.

#### Count uniques by combo

If the number of combos is small, you could try counting the number of unique cards drawn in each combo:

```
def next_state(state, outcome, count):
    state = list(state or [0] * NUM_COMBOS)
    if count > 0:
        for combo in COMBOS[outcome]
            state[combo] += 1
    return tuple(state)
```

Then at the end you would determine which (possibly partial) combo gives the best payoff.

### Linearity of expectation

If all you are interested in is the expected value, and you can factor out a purely additive component, then you can take advantage of linearity of expectation. For example, suppose you can split the payoff into the sum of:

- A fixed "tech" value per card, which are unconditionally summed.
- The value-above-tech of the best combo.

Then you can sum the expected value of the two components to get the overall expected value. The first one is just the expected tech value per card times the hand size, and the second one can be computed more efficiently since you no longer need the joint distribution with the tech value.

### Code example

This uses my [Icepool Python library](https://github.com/HighDiceRoller/icepool). The idea is to split into three components:

- Base values for each card, which are added together unconditionally.
- Inclusive combos, which can each be scored at most once.
- Exclusive combos, which only the highest is scored.

The three components are not independent, but this doesn't matter for the expected value. They could be computed jointly for some extra cost.

There are some differences in payoff matrix compared to the example question; I tried to follow the text rather than the literal numbers provided.

```
from icepool import Deck, ContainsSubsetEvaluator, JointEvaluator, SumEvaluator

deck = Deck({'G': 3, 'S': 3, 'F': 3, 'JJ': 3, 'T': 28})
deal = deck.deal(6)

# Each card unconditionally contributes this value.
# Duplicates count multiple times.
base_values = {
    'G': 2,
    'S': 1,
    'F': 1,
    'JJ': 1,
    'T': 2,
}

base_score = deal.sum(sub=base_values)

print('Base score:')
print(base_score)
print('Mean:', base_score.mean())
print()


# Each of these combos can be scored up to once.
inclusive_combos = [
    ({'F'}, 0.7),
]

inclusive_score = sum(value * deal.contains_subset(combo)
                      for combo, value in inclusive_combos)

print('Inclusive combo score:')
print(inclusive_score)
print('Mean:', inclusive_score.mean())
print()

# Only the max of these combos is scored.
exclusive_combos = [
    ({'G', 'S'}, 3),
    ({'S', 'F'}, 4),
    ({'G', 'JJ'}, 1),
]

# Jointly evaluate whether each combo was gotten.
# This is not the most efficient possible,
# though it is more efficient than enumerating
# all possible hands.
# IntersectionSizeEvaluator could be used in place
# of ContainsSubsetEvaluator.
exclusive_evaluator = JointEvaluator(
        *(ContainsSubsetEvaluator(combo)
          for combo, _ in exclusive_combos))

exclusive_gots = exclusive_evaluator.evaluate(deal)

# Then pick the max gotten combo value.
def score_exclusive(gots):
    return max(
        got * value
        for got, (_, value) in zip(gots, exclusive_combos))

exclusive_score = exclusive_gots.sub(score_exclusive)
print('Exclusive combos:')
print(exclusive_score)
print('Mean:', exclusive_score.mean())
print()

print('Overall mean:',
      base_score.mean() + inclusive_score.mean() + exclusive_score.mean())
```

Result:

Base score:
Die with denominator 3838380

| Outcome | Quantity | Probability |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 84 | 0.002188% |
| 7 | 3906 | 0.101762% |
| 8 | 58590 | 1.526425% |
| 9 | 377580 | 9.836962% |
| 10 | 1132740 | 29.510887% |
| 11 | 1529199 | 39.839698% |
| 12 | 736281 | 19.182077% |

Mean: 10.65

Inclusive combo score:
Die with denominator 3838380

| Outcome | Quantity | Probability |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.0 | 2324784 | 60.566802% |
| 0.7 | 1513596 | 39.433198% |

Mean: 0.2760323886639676

Exclusive combos:
Die with denominator 3838380

| Outcome | Quantity | Probability |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2562150 | 66.750817% |
| 1 | 371257 | 9.672232% |
| 3 | 371257 | 9.672232% |
| 4 | 533716 | 13.904720% |

Mean: 0.9430780693938589

Overall mean: 11.869110458057827

### The algorithm

The algorithm itself is based on the decomposition of the multivariate hypergeometric formula as a product of binomials. Combined with the transition function formulation above, this allows us to memoize intermediate results at each step, in other words, "what would the state distribution be if I drew only $0 \ldots k$ cards, all of which are class $1 \ldots M$ or lower". For the details, you can read [my paper](https://ojs.aaai.org/index.php/AIIDE/article/view/21971).

```
@inproceedings{liu2022icepool,
    title={Icepool: Efficient Computation of Dice Pool Probabilities},
    author={Albert Julius Liu},
    booktitle={Eighteenth AAAI Conference on Artificial Intelligence and Interactive Digital Entertainment},
    volume={18},
    number={1},
    pages={258-265},
    year={2022},
    month={Oct.},
    eventdate={2022-10-24/2022-10-28},
    venue={Pomona, California},
    url={https://ojs.aaai.org/index.php/AIIDE/article/view/21971},
    doi={10.1609/aiide.v18i1.21971}
}
```

Comment: I tried reading the paper, but it is honestly pretty opaque to me.  Could you describe more clearly how you would compute the $\mathbb E[\max ...]$?

I added an example to my question. You can see that the matrix is not very large (in this simplified example), but there is no sparsity, though perhaps one could subtract $2$ from everything.

Comment: The output of the algorithm is the full distribution of max payoffs, from which you can take the weighted mean as usual. I'm not familiar with Yugioh specifically, but I'll think about your example. If the example is representative, perhaps you could decompose the matrix into a sparse component of explicit combos; maxed with a "tech" component where each card has a fixed base and tech value, and payoffs are equal to the base of one card + the tech of the other, i.e. the matrix is the outer sum of two vectors.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I will try to check it out more thoroughly in the future. If I understood you correctly you are already highlighting a very natural extension, that any tech cards gives you a flat bonus, so ideally you want the best combo plus the remaining cards all tech cards (this is no longer in the "2-card combo" setting). It would be great if such a decomposition would also come with a performance boost. It's somewhat representative, although the amount of tech cards is usually 15 or less. I left out a lot of weird combinations that would require even more complicated formulations.

Comment: Yes, one way of looking at the algorithm is that it reduces the problem of performance to one of state space minimization; the decompositions are various ways of using structure to reduce the state space. Unfortunately this does mean this is very much "some assembly required", though I may look into including some more unique-counting methods with the library.

Comment: Added some notes on computational complexity and linearity of expectation. At some point I hope to add a code example, though I need to do some API work first.